# How to download CSV file from function in WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I've built a plugin for a client so that they can download data as a CSV file. It's been set up so that when the user clicks on a link in the menu, the CSV should just automatically download. However, it doesn't quite work like that, and just loads the function as a page in the WordPress backend.

This is the code I have for the function:

```
function download_payment_csv() {
    include 'lib/connection.php';

    $csv_output = '';

    $values = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tbPayments ORDER BY date DESC');

    $i=0;

    while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
        for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
            $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].",";
        }
        $csv_output .= "\n";
    }

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.csv\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    echo $csv_output;

}
```

And as I said, it just returns a blank screen. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
So this is the code I'm now working with, taking bits from what's been said already.

```
function download_payment_csv() {

    include 'lib/connection.php';

    $csv_output = '';

    $values = load_payment_csv();

    $fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

    $file = 'test_export';
    $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".csv");
    // Disable caching
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
    header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");

    if(count($values) > 0) {
        foreach($values as $result) {
            fputcsv($fp, $result);
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);

}
```

This generates a CSV, but there is a problem with it.The problem is that when viewing the page it doesn't download it as a CSV, it just outputs the contents of the CSV in to the page. However, adding this function to the top of the plugin:

```
add_action('admin_init','download_payment_csv');
```

This then triggers a download when the menu link is clicked, which is fine. But it triggers it for every menu item in the plugin, which is wrong. It should only trigger when the download link is clicked.

Comment: if you just echo `$csv_output` ; do you get any output?

Comment: When it loads as just function, does it contains any output? Also **don't use mysql_, use PDO or mysqli_**

Comment: I get absolutely no output when just echo'ing $csv_output when it's loaded as just the function

Comment: It seems you never assign $i to something else than 0, therefore the for loop will never run because $j<$i (which is 0) - and it only adds the \n symbols

Answer (score 13):

/**
 * Query For Top Title Row
 */

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table" );
if(count($results) > 0){
    foreach($results as $result){
        $csv_output .= str_replace('_',' ',$result->Field).", "; // , or ;      
    }
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
```

/**
 * Query For All Required Data
 */

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table",ARRAY_A );
if(count($results) > 0){
    foreach($results as $result){
        $result = array_values($result);
        $result = implode(", ", $result);
        $csv_output .= $result."\n"; 
    }
}
```

/**
 * Prepare Filename And CSV File to export
 */

```
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
```

Putting this all in a function should do the trick

Comment: This is great dude :)

Comment: This is good, but I'm getting errors saying that the header information can't be modified?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
<?php

class CSVExport
{
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    if(isset($_GET['download_report']))
    {
        $csv = $this->generate_csv();

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.csv\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        echo $csv;
        exit;
    }

    // Add extra menu items for admins
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'admin_menu'));

    // Create end-points
    add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'query_vars'));
    add_action('parse_request', array($this, 'parse_request'));
}

/**
 * Add extra menu items for admins
 */
public function admin_menu()
{
    add_menu_page('Download Report', 'Download Report', 'manage_options', 'download_report', array($this, 'download_report'));
}

/**
 * Allow for custom query variables
 */
public function query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'download_report';
    return $query_vars;
}

/**
 * Parse the request
 */
public function parse_request(&$wp)
{
    if(array_key_exists('download_report', $wp->query_vars))
    {
        $this->download_report();
        exit;
    }
}

/**
 * Download report
 */
public function download_report()
{
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>';
    echo '<h2>Download Report</h2>';
    //$url = site_url();

    echo '<p><a href="site_url()/wp-admin/admin.php?page=download_report&download_report">Export the Subscribers</a>';
}

/**
 * Converting data to CSV
 */
public function generate_csv()
{
    $csv_output = '';
    $table = 'users';

    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");

    $i = 0;
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $csv_output = $csv_output . $row['Field'].",";
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";

    $values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
    while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
        for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
            $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].",";
        }
        $csv_output .= "\n";
    }

    return $csv_output;
}
}

// Instantiate a singleton of this plugin
$csvExport = new CSVExport();
```

Comment: Pretty major security issue here... anyone can download the report by simply guessing the `download_report` parameter...

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to change some header information

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="report.csv"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
```

After that make use of php://output for providing the data directly to the browser, this will prevent the blank page.

for example:

```
$outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach($result as $result)
{
    fputcsv($outstream, $result);
}

fclose($outstream);
exit();
```

php://output is a read only stream that allows you provide data directly to the requester.

EDIT: Also you should make use of $wpdb

Comment: This still dumps HTML code at the top of the file in a front side wordpress environment

Comment: You're calling this inside your template this is meant to be called by a GET request not associated with your template.

Comment: Might be a bit late for @DebbieKurth but add `ob_end_clean();` - `Place, ob_end_clean(); before you output the csv. "Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering" - PHP manual.`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found, after having tons of trouble with the code outputting HTML code, when used on the front side of the site.  The key is to exchange exit for 'die'. This is the code I am using on my own sites.

````
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
$FileName = 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. 'Report.csv"';
header($FileName);

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    
$header_row = array(
        0 => 'data1',
        1 => 'data2',
        2 => 'data3',
    );
fputcsv($fp, $header_row); 

$rows = GetDataBaseData();
if(!empty($rows)) 
  {
   foreach($rows as $Record)
     {      
    // where data1, data2, data3 are the database column names 
    $OutputRecord = array($Record['data1'], $Record['data1'], $Record['data1']);
    fputcsv($fp, $OutputRecord);         
    }
    unset($rows);
  }

fclose( $fp );
    
die;   <===== key point.  Use DIE not Exit.  Exit will only work on the back end. Die will work on both.
```

Works on the front and backend of wordpress.
````